# CUDA 6.0 cudaMallocManaged error

Tags: cuda

I downloaded the CUDA 6.0 RC, and wrote a simple program to test the unified memory. But I got a **cudaErrorNotSupported** error when I run to **cudaMallocManaged** function. My GPU is GeForce GT 620, is there any problem with the GPU?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unified Memory in CUDA 6 requires a cc 3.0 or higher device  -- this is noted in the documentation for Unified Memory usage in the CUDA 6 programming guide.

Your GeForce [GT 620 GPU is a cc 2.1 device](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus).

Unified Memory features (including `cudaMallocManaged`) are not supported on cc2.1 devices.

Comment: Do you know if there is a hardware reason for this, or if it's due to lack of regression testing? In [Mark Harris' CUDA 6 presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PbPK_lmUsRU) he mentions that hardware support for Unified Memory is introduced in Maxwell.

Comment: Roger, I'm not sure what I can say publicly, so I shall have to say I'm unable to answer your question.  Perhaps @harrism will see this and be able to comment.  I don't believe pre - cc 3.0 devices were excluded based purely on limited QA or test resources.  I believe there were functional differences between Fermi and Kepler which also contributed.  And there are future evolutions of UM that will behave significantly differently than the UM that is exposed in CUDA 6.   Sorry I can't be of further assistance.

Comment: Thanks, Robert. Didn't intend to put you on the spot for trade secrets.